# JavaFx: ObservableHashSet

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, observable, hashset

I was wondering in `FxCollections` there are many methods for creating the observable variant of a "simple" `Collection` like `ArrayList` or of a `HashMap`, but I don't find an `.observableHashSet` for example.

I know I can create by using `FxCollections.observableSet(new HashSet<>())`
but there are also methods for creating an observable `ArrayList` like: 
`FxCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<>())`

Even if you want to use the `ovservableSet(E... elements)` method a new `HashSet` is created, why is creating an empty set a problem?

Is there any purpose of skipping this method from the `FxCollections` class or they just thought it is not as used as the `ArrayList` or `HashMap` version?

Java version: 8u121.

Comment: I'd ask the opposite question: why is there a separate `observableArrayList()` when there is also an `observableArrayList(E...)` which does exactly the same thing. My guess is it's for back-compatibility, somehow. Just use `observableSet(E...)` to create an empty set.

Comment: Yeah and I've just observed that the `observableArrayList()` is without generic type while the `observableHashMap` has...Interesting. I've also thought there could be the back-compatibility, but I don't really see what could go wrong if you add the HashSet version or remove those two for the arraylist and hashmap.

Comment: The `observableArrayList()` with no parameters is a generic method. It's not really clear what you're asking here: are you now saying there should be an `observableHashSet(E...)` that does exactly the same as `observableSet(E...)`?

Comment: I mean I would expect a generic method `observableHashSet()` with no parameters as the arraylist version has. But while it can be used the method with varargs, probably there is no sense to create it. Anyway, it was just a curiosity if there is a purpose of making such a difference between the arraylist's and the set's version

Comment: Besides note the argument type `observableSet​(Set<E> set)` vs `observableArrayList​(Collection<? extends E> col)`.